# Why is the 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' assembly not loading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've browsed multiple questions where people have experienced similar errors, but none of the accepted solutions seem to work in my case. My application is having trouble loading the correct assembly for Razor (System.Web.WebPages.Razor). Here's the Assembly Load Trace:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/map2/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\map2\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\map2\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/bb3877fb/1ffa8a7e/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/bb3877fb/1ffa8a7e/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/map2/bin/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I don't know what I need to correct it. Should I use an assembly redirect? Should I try to replace the current Razor dll? I've seen a few people try to use them on some other questions here, but I'm not sure how I can do this. Here's a slightly censored version of my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MAP;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="MAPEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.MapModel.csdl|res://*/Model.MapModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.MapModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=MAP;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   <add name="MAPConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MAP;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <!--<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />-->
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an assembly reference in your web.config. Have you tried adding the Razor assembly in?

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

EDIT 1
You can try adding a binding redirect per @StevenV

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. It seems that it's reference is there, but it's looking for the wrong version of it. As you can see, it's looking for 1.0.0.0, but my DLL shows the version 2.0.20710.0.

Comment: @MartinTracey Possibly use assembly redirection to make `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` version 1.0.0.0 redirect to 2.0.0.0 along with this solution?